# Difficulty including script tag using @HTML.Raw

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to include the script tag below using @HTML.Raw method:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/App/durandal/amd/require.js" data-main="@Url.Content("~/App/main")"></script>
```

I am having problems including the data-main attribute.

This is what I have tried:

```
@Html.Raw("<script type='text/javascript' src='~/App/durandal/amd/require.js' data-main="@Url.Content("~/App/main")"></script>");
```

Comment: what is the reason to use @html.raw to load javascript file

Comment: I want to load that javascript file only when user is authenticated using Google+ Sign In. I get to know if the user is authenticated within a javascript function of a .cshtml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve by using @html.raw, you can do something like this:

```
@Html.Raw(String.Format("<script type='text/javascript'
                         src='~/App/durandal/amd/require.js' 
                         data-main={0}></script>"
                        ,@Url.Content("~/App/main")))
```